# Scale/zoom div content dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have try css transform, zoom, jquery... about 10+ demos and libraries to zoom/scale content most of them are for images...

Initial js

```
var hew = $(window).height();
var hes = hew - 100; // 100 is the total height of .margins-heads
$(".wrapper").css({height: hes, overflow: 'hidden'});
```

Initial html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row clearfix margins-heads">
     <div class="col-sm-3">Some logo</div>
     <div class="col-sm-9">Menu...</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row clearfix">
     <div class="col-sm-3">Side navigation</div>
     <div class="col-sm-9">
         <div class="center-content">
              <div class="wrapper">
                  <div>Content single img and name</div>
                  <div>about a hundred of this div's...</div>
                  <div>You get the picture...</div>
              </div>
         </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

so usually the height for .wrapper is gonna be 548px unless you have a huge monitor it could be 700px height... the point is that everything inside .wrapper has to be scaled to fit in there, now, every element inside has a width of 10% with the image height of 60px max...
I have use transform: scale(0.7); but the thing is that the value has to be dynamically base on the height of the div.wrapper ... and there is where I'm stuck... I have try Zoomooz.js, but that only zooms in and it doesn't scale the content to fit my div.wrapper ... any help would greatly appreciated...

** Update

https://fiddle.jshell.net/4ww87obb/1/

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle please?

Comment: Please post the code in a snippet ([See illustration](http://i.imgur.com/p94EZRA.png?1)), [jsFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net), [PenCode.io](http://pencode.io), or [Plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co)

Comment: use `$(window).resize()` to get the height when resized

Answer (score 0):

You can use vw or vh to make your page responsive. Ex:

```
width:100vw;
```

this maximizes width based on the width of your browser. Vh changes the attribute based on the height of your browser.